# how edit and Customization html-css notfound page and sighnup page of keycloak?

Tags: html, css, keycloak

I want to edit not-found page and sign-up page in key-cloak but i don't know how i can. i edit login page by adding login file into my login directory. but what about not found and sign up ?

I just can edit some phrases in messages_en.properties file just for translating to another phrases but like login, I want edit basically.

Comment: Check the documentation on how to add a theme. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes